# problem with log into epson tm-m30 printer

Tags: printing, setup

I have a problem logging into an epson tm-m30 printer. I have google search everywhere and all seem to say the username and password for accessing the printer is epson and epson. I have tried that and everything else like admin and admin and admin and 0000 and ...etc and nothing have worked out so far. I have spent 3 day searching for it but no luck so far.

I want to set a static IP address to the printer which I need to access the printer and change the IP address. I have also tried to plug ethernet to my laptop but still cannot login as I don't know the username and password. Also tried to factory reset it and still not working.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with a Mac, really, other than that the user is probably using a Mac to try to configure the printer. :)

Comment: You don't need direct access to any network device to set a static IP address - you need access to the router, specifically its DHCP server. From there you set a static lease, tied to the device's MAC address.

Comment: @Tetsujin While true, most point-of-sale devices assume a standard, documented static IP address.  The M30 is an outlier in that by default it assumes DHCP rather than having to be configured to do so.  I didn't really want to get into the whole "reset the printer, plug it into the network, wait for it to get an IP, print the status report to find out what IP it got" cycle with the OP.  Easier to put a crossover cable between the printer and

Comment: @MarcWilson - as the OP seems to be having little joy in connecting to the printer itself I just thought I'd suggest an alternative, which circumvents the need to get to the printer at all. My own printer I think just got assigned a random IP from the pool, which I then fixed at the gateway. 5 min job, set & forget.

Answer (score 1):

If someone has changed the credentials on the printer, then really the only thing you can do is reset it to factory defaults.

- 1 After running a self test, hold down the Feed button for at least
  one second to enter the Mode selection. The Mode selection guidance
  is printed, and the Paper LED flashes.
- 2 Briefly press the Feed button five times (less than one second),
  hold it down for at least one second to enter the Interface Setup
  mode. The guidance is printed.
- 3 After briefly pressing the Feed button (less than one second) for
  the number of times shown in the print result, hold down the button
  for more than one second to select the setting items.

Initialize:
Select [Wi-Fi & Ethernet Setup] or [Bluetooth Setup] and select [Initialize] to initialize the communication
settings. The printer is reset and restarted.

You don't need to set a static IP address on the printer to configure it, it will have one by default after the reset.  Put your laptop on the same subnet as the printer and you will be able to communicate with it.  By default the printer will have the IP address 192.168.192.168 if it can't reach a DHCP server.

Comment: I have tried all of that what you suggested but still cannot log in. I'm not sure what else I should do

Answer (score 0):

With the latest firmware and for security reason, the login and password is no longer epson and epson.

**ID:** epson

**Password:** serial number of the device

I'm also on MacOS and it's not simple to update the firmware to the latest version.